# Inverse of [a]ₓ [b]ₓ + [a × b]ₓ

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

For vectors **a**, **b** in ℝ³, define a matrix
  M(**a**, **b**) = [**a**]ₓ [**b**]ₓ + [**a** × **b**]ₓ.

Here, [⋅]ₓ is the cross-product matrix map, so for **c** in ℝ³, 
M(**a**, **b**) **c**   =   [**a**]ₓ [**b**]ₓ **c** + [**a** × **b**]ₓ **c**   =   **a** × (**b** × **c**) + (**a** × **b**) × **c**.

I can show that M(**a**, **b**) is non-singular unless **a**⊥**b** or **a**∥**b**. 
Is there a simple expression for M(**a**, **b**)⁻¹, the inverse matrix?

UPDATE - What I have so far:

$\def\a{\mathbf{a}} \def\b{\mathbf{b}}$
Alternate formula for $M(\a, \b)$:

$$
M(\a, \b) \;=\; 2 \b \a^T - \a \b^T - (\a\cdot\b)I.
$$

Effect on selected vectors:
$$
M(\a, \b)\, \a \;=\; 2 (\a\times\b) \times \a \;=\; 2 ((\a\cdot\a)\,\b - (\a\cdot\b)\, \a),
$$
$$
M(\a, \b)\, \b \;=\; \;(\a\times\b) \times \b \;=\;  \;((\a\cdot\b)\,\b - (\b\cdot\b)\, \a),
$$
$$
M(\a, \b)\, \a\times\b \;=\; -(\a\cdot\b)\,\a\times\b.
$$

Using this to assemble a matrix expression:
$$
M(\a, \b) = 
U
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\,\a\cdot\b & -\b\cdot\b & 0 \\
2\,\a\cdot\a & \a\cdot\b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\a\cdot\b
\end{bmatrix}
U^{-1},
$$
with $U = \begin{bmatrix}\a,&\b,&\a\times\b\end{bmatrix}$ and
$$
U^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
-((\a\times\b)\times\b)^T \\
((\a\times\b)\times\a)^T \\
(\a\times\b)^T
\end{bmatrix} \,/\, \|\a\times\b\|^2.
$$

The inverse of the matrix expression is then
$$
M(\a,\b)^{-1} = U
\begin{bmatrix}
\a\cdot\b\,/\,D & \b\cdot\b\,/\,D & 0 \\
-2\,\a\cdot\a\,/\,D & -2\,\a\cdot\b\,/\,D & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1/(\a\cdot\b)
\end{bmatrix}
U^{-1},
$$
where $D = 2\|\a\times\b\|^2$.

It's getting pretty close to something usable. It looks like it might simplify well, fingers crossed.

UPDATE -

The best I can come up with is
$$
M(\a,\b)^{-1} \;=\; 
\frac{(\a\cdot\b)(\a\b^T - 2\b\a^T) - 2(\a\times\b)(\a\times\b)^T}
{2\,(\a\cdot\b)\,\|\a\times\b\|^2}
$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks, @CyclotomicField, I've added an update. Writing it out helped a lot. I think I'm nearing the home stretch.